# Reading an Excel file with fs.createReadStream

Tags: node.js, excel, fs

I am new to node js
I want to print excel data without using any library as using libraries takes time and we have to deal with large memory files.
I tried reading a `.xlsx` file using `fs.createReadStream()` and logged the data to console, it prints some different characters but the actual data.

### nodejs code

```
const stream=fs.createReadStream('example.xlsx');
stream.on('data',function(data){
   console.log(Buffer.from(data, 'base64').toString('utf8'))
})
```

Can I know how to get the actual data or any library that can read large excel files?

Comment: You can use this library for reading and writing excel files in node. Writing the code for reading a xlsx file from scratch could be a big task. So instead use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs

Comment: will this be faster even for some million rows of data with multiple sheets?

Comment: can we run this exceljs asynchronously?

Comment: yes you can and for a million records, use the streaming way to read xlsx in there

Comment: in their documentation they have not given any example on streaming for reading , they have given example for writing though. i have seen a conversation in github where they said "Hi work on workbook reader is paused - there are memory issues with the implementation that I'm not happy with so I haven't properly released it yet. As always, when time allows I hope to work on it."